# C# - PeopleAPI : The format of the value '<name solution> google-api-dotnet-client/1.45.0.0 (gzip)' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, google-api, google-people-api

I need help with Google People API. I'm tryng to create a create contact request in my account loggedd in but at the moment of executing the request it throws the exception above. I get the people service from the data (token, scopes, refresh token, ...) from the token file in App_Data in the folder People.Api.Auth.Store and assign them when creating the token response then I create the user credentials, etc.
I've seen it working but when AuthorizationCodeMvcApp is used instead. But because I want to create that contact from a request of a web service I can't get the controller from the other project (because of the dependencies).
May someone help please?
Thanks!!!

The exception is thrown in the last line:

```
Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest peopleRequest = new Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.PeopleResource.CreateContactRequest(oService, oPerson);

Google.Apis.PeopleService.v1.Data.Person personNew = peopleRequest.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok i solve the problem thanks to the following that iss the same I asked.

[Gmail API - The format of value '= Get Labels google-api-dotnet-client/1.25.0.0 (gzip)' is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518129/gmail-api-the-format-of-value-get-labels-google-api-dotnet-client-1-25-0-0)

My AppName was "Gestión.." and the issue was in the 'ó', I changed it to 'o' and it worked.